# Helm: How to Override Value with Periods in Name

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am trying to script setup of Jenkins so that I can create and tear down Jenkins clusters programmatically with helm. I've hit an annoying snag where I cannot set a key with dots in the name. My helm values.yaml file looks like this:

```
---
rbac:
  install: true

Master:
  HostName: jenkins.mycompany.com
  ServiceType: ClusterIP
  ImageTag: lts
  InstallPlugins:
    - kubernetes
    - workflow-aggregator
    - workflow-job
    - credentials-binding
    - git
    - blueocean
    - github
    - github-oauth

  ScriptApproval:
    - "method groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic parseText java.lang.String"
    - "new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic"
    - "staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods leftShift java.util.Map java.util.Map"
    - "staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods split java.lang.String"
    - "method java.util.Collection toArray"
    - "staticMethod org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker checkedCall java.lang.Object boolean boolean java.lang.String java.lang.Object[]"
    - "staticMethod org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker checkedGetProperty java.lang.Object boolean boolean java.lang.Object"

  Ingress:
    Annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    TLS:
      - secretName: jenkins-mycompany-com
        hosts:
          - jenkins.mycompany.com

  Memory: "2Gi"
  # This breaks the init container
  # RunAsUser: 1000
  # FSGroup: 1000

Agent:
  Enabled: false
  ImageTag: latest
```

After installing `cert-manager`, `external-dns`, `nginx-ingress` (for now via a bash script) I install it like so:

```
helm install --values helm/jenkins.yml stable/jenkins
```

I failed to read the letsencrypt docs at all, so throughout the course of testing I used my production quota. I want to be able to add an annotation to the `Ingress`: `certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging` so that I can continue testing (and set this as the default in the future, overriding when I'm ready for production).

The trouble is... I can't figure out how to pass this via the `--set` flag, since there are periods in the key name. I've tried:

```
helm install --values helm/jenkins.yml stable/jenkins --set Master.Ingress.Annotations.certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer=letsencrypt-staging
```

and

```
helm install --values helm/jenkins.yml stable/jenkins --set Master.Ingress.Annotations.certmanager\.k8s\.io/cluster-issuer=letsencrypt-staging
```

I can of course solve this by adding a value that I use as a flag, but it's less explicit. Is there any way to set it directly?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You need to enclose the key with quotations and then escape the dots

```
helm install --values helm/jenkins.yml stable/jenkins --set Master.Ingress.Annotations."certmanager\.k8s\.io/cluster-issuer"=letsencrypt-staging
```

Answer (score 15):

Use `\` to escape the dots in the key. Quotation marks are required to prevent shell interpreting the `\` character.

```
helm install --values helm/jenkins.yml stable/jenkins --set 'Master.Ingress.Annotations.certmanager\.k8s\.io/cluster-issuer=letsencrypt-staging'
```

Helm requires these characters to be escaped: `.` `[` `,` `=`

Source: https://paul-boone.medium.com/helm-chart-install-advanced-usage-of-the-set-argument-3e214b69c87a

Comment: I had to use this (single quotes). I'm on ubuntu and using the double quotes in the accepted answer didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone try to do so from Powershell/PWSH

```
--set "server.serviceAccount.annotations.azure\.workload\.identity/client-id=$identity"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in Jenkins within a shell script like this:

```
sh """
...
--set-string datasources.'datasources\\.yaml'.datasources[1].secureJsonData.token=$TOKEN \
...
"""
```

I'm not sure if this is the best explanation but I'll give it a shot....
Groovy interprets shell scripts with backslashes differently than a normal shell script because in Jenkins this is being written inside a shell script. The double escape is needed so Groovy ignores the first backslash and then helm ignores the second. This problem took me too long to solve so I'd figure I'd share what I found for anyone stuck in the same boat.