# Dynamic ConfigMap Helm Template with nested curly braces

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have the following files

### mychart/templates/configmap.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.env.{{lle.dev}} }}-configmap
data:
  myvalue: "Hello World"
```

### mychart/values.yaml

```
env:
  lle.dev: ABC
  lle.qa: CDE
```

How do I access the values in the helm template? nested curly braces are also not allowed. Also the below didn't work

```
name: {{ .Values.env.lle.dev }}-configmap
```

Reason being it is considering lle, dev as a separate sub keys for env and not as a single key.

Comment: This is a duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53340475/is-it-possible-to-use-a-template-inside-a-template-with-go-template). Please see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53446888/7568391)

Comment: @edbighead I did not find the answer for my problem.

Comment: You can access values with {{ .Values.env.lle.dev }}

Comment: it won't work. I tried it already.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are trying to prefix your variables with `lle`? If not, you can rewrite your `values.yaml` file in the following way:

```
env:
  lle: 
    dev: ABC
    qa: CDE
```

Then you will be able to access your variables as in `name: {{ .Values.env.lle.dev }}-configmap`

Comment: I'm using some other long key which contains period in it

Comment: Please see related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49522776/helm-how-to-override-value-with-periods-in-name